# gitinfo2 Only display branch when not on master

Tags: conditionals, git, gitinfo

I am currently using the `gitinfo2` package in my document to display the current git revision, branch, and date. However, I would only like to display the branch if I am not on the master branch. This will require some conditional wrapping around `\gitBranch` but I couldn't figure this out.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{gitinfo2}
% additional install is required. See package documentation for details.

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\ \\
\vspace{5cm}
{\Huge Document title}
\vspace{5cm}

Revision: \gitAbbrevHash on branch \gitBranch \ \gitCommitterDate

\end{titlepage}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

So far, I've tried this, with no success:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{gitinfo2}
% additional install is required. See package documentation for details.
\newcommand{\masterBranch}{master}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\ \\
\vspace{5cm}
{\Huge Document title}
\vspace{5cm}

Revision: \gitAbbrevHash

\if\gitBranch\masterBranch
\else
    on branch \gitBranch
\fi

\ \gitCommitterDate

\end{titlepage}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

- The test `\if` expands the next tokens until it finds two unexpandable tokens for comparison. Therefore, it cannot be used to compare macro definitions.
  The switch `\ifx` is better suited here, because it compares the next two tokens without expanding.
- `\gitBranch` does not contain the name of the branch directly, instead is uses expandable (I hope always) macros to get the name. Also `\detokenize` is used to convert the characters to tokens with category code 12 (other), like digits and punctuation characters.

That means:

- Use of `\ifx` instead of `\if`.
- `\edef\gitBranch{\gitBranch}` to get a macro with the expanded branch name.
- `\edef\branchMaster{\detokenize{master}}` to get the correct category codes.

Result:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{gitinfo2}

\edef\masterBranch{\detokenize{master}}
\edef\gitBranch{\gitBranch}

\begin{document}
Revision: \gitAbbrevHash\ %
%
\ifx\gitBranch\masterBranch
\else
    on branch \gitBranch\ %
\fi
%
\gitCommitterDate
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]